# How to change angular-material directive and compile it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, compilation, angular-material

If I compile native html element it works fine.

But if I compile compile Angular Material element (md-button) in console shows "Error: [ngTransclude:orphan]".

I am totally tired and can't figure it out.
I need to get html code from template, I know when we create element from string value and compile it, it work's fine. Maybe it must to be used $mdCompiler, but I don't know how.

Here is a little and simple example, please help me.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak>
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <mydir></mydir>
 </div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
 console.log("\n\n\n\n\n");
 console.clear();
 
    var app = angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);
 
 app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {  } );
 
 app.directive('mydir', ['$compile', function($compile){
  return {
   scope: {
   },
   template: 
    "<md-button>md Button</md-button>" + 
    "<button>Native Button</button>" + 
    "<span> HelpMePlease </span>", 
   restrict: "E",
   link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.fn = function () { console.log("Hello"); };

    var mdButton = element.find("button").eq(0);
    mdButton.attr("ng-click", "fn()");
    $compile(mdButton)(scope);
    console.log(mdButton[0]);

    var button = element.find("button").eq(1);
    button.attr("ng-click", "fn()");
    $compile(button)(scope);
    console.log(button[0]);
   }
  };
 } ] );
 
  </script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `md-button` already compiled.

Maybe, you can use this.

Example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/j9ppuhap/).

```js
var app = angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {});

app.directive('mydir', ['$compile', '$mdCompiler', function($compile, $mdCompiler) {
  return {
    scope: {},
    template:"<button>Native Button</button>" +
      "<span> HelpMePlease </span>",
    restrict: "E",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.fn = function() {
        console.log("Hello");
      };

      $mdCompiler.compile({
        template: '<md-button ng-click ="fn()" >md Button</md-button>'
      }).then(function(compileData) {
        compileData.link(scope);
        element.prepend(compileData.element);
      });

      var button = element.find("button").eq(0);
      button.attr("ng-click", "fn()");
      $compile(button)(scope);
    }
  };
}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body ng-app="BlankApp" ng-cloak>
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <mydir></mydir>
  </div>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.1/angular-material.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```